# Is it possible to use PCRE2 on variables in bash

Tags: bash, pcre

I'm trying to use PCRE2 on stdin in a bash script but I'm not sure it's possible based on reading the docs. I know I can give it the filename but I'm doing a test and it specifically says on stdin.

For example I have this text in input.txt

```
foo blah is a bar
this shouldn't work
```

I then call this command: `cat input.txt | sh program.sh "foo %{0} is a %{1S3}"`

Which fires this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Give access to Elixir module
chmod +x ./lib/my_mod.ex

# Get arg passed to program.sh
token=$1

# Create array for cat and insert into it
array=()
while IFS= read line; do
array+=("${line}")
        done

# Get regex based on pattern sequence
regex=$(mix run -e "my_mod.main('${token}')")

pcre "${regex}" ./input.txt

# Call pcre2grep on each item and match with regex
# for value in "${array[@]}"
# do
#      echo "${value}"
#      pcre2grep "${regex}" "${value}"
# done
```

This works: `pcre "${regex}" ./input.txt`

This doesn't

```
# Call pcre2grep on each item and match with regex
    for value in "${array[@]}"
    do
         echo "${value}"
         pcre2grep "${regex}" "${value}"
    done
```

I'm supposed to use PCRE (Or supposedly PCRE2) but I feel like I'm doing something stupid.

Any ideas on if this is possible using PCRE?

Thanks
Nick

**Update**

If I hard code the regex returned from `$(mix run -e "my_mod.main('${token}')")` it doesn't work but if I hardcode the regex, it does work:

`pcre2grep "foo [a-zA-Z ]{0,} is a \W*(\w+(\W+|$)){1,4}$"`

Calling Mix is affecting `cat input.txt | sh program.sh "foo %{0} is a %{1S3}"`

Comment: `I'm not sure it's possible based on reading the doc` My `man pcre2grep` state `If  no  files  are specified, pcre2grep reads the standard input. The standard input can also be referenced by a name consisting of a single hyphen.`. What docs are you reading?

Comment: @KamilCuk I've been reading the docs here: https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2grep.html

Comment: The same text is present in the documentation you posted.

Comment: @KamilCuk Do you want to change your answer and I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run it, just like grep:

```
regex=$(mix run -e "my_mod.main('${token}')" <&-)
pcre2grep "${regex}"
```

---

It happens that `mix` is reading from standard input, leaving nothing for `pcre2grep` to read. Close standard input for the process with `<&-`.

Comment: When I run the script like that, the terminal is empty. When I supply an argument of filename, it prints out the matches. This leads me to believe it's not working correctly like that.

Comment: I do not know what `mix` is. Please try `cat input.txt | pcre2grep 'foo .* is a .*'`

Comment: Mix is Elixir, I'm generating a regex with some logic and then returning it to be used in the script.

Comment: `cat input.txt | pcre2grep 'foo .* is a .*'` works for me. But ideally I want to use the regex generated by`regex=$(mix run -e "my_mod.main('${token}')")`

Comment: Then the regex generated by that is invalid. Run your script with `set -x` and debug it.

Comment: I've hardcoded the regex and it works, the call to `$(mix run -e "my_mod.main('${token}')")` stops it from working regardless of if I use it's regex or not. This is the regex: `pcre2grep "foo [a-zA-Z ]{0,} is a \W*(\w+(\W+|$)){1,4}$"`

Comment: Try `regex=$(mix run -e "my_mod.main('${token}')" <&-)`

Comment: That works, `regex=$(mix run -e "my_mod.main('${token}')" <&-)` what does the `<&-` mean? Do you want to put it as the right answer and I can accept it.